# Java Tetris 2 player multiplayer GUI not working properly

Tags: java, swing

basically i am working on a tetris game and i want to implement a 2 player versus mode.
for now i have a working single player and now i want to make a gui for  a 2 player multiplayer. (i will make a second keylistener and a endGame condition later)
however, when i add both gamepanels (what displays the state of the game after retreiving the state of the game from the boardhandler (1 or 2 depending on which player)) i dont get a correct display/gui.
this is what it looks like:
https://gyazo.com/58f37beab249c975cd4acdb8ae0e0154
this is what it should look like (but i want 2 boards displayed since this screenshot is from singleplayerwindow):
https://gyazo.com/4aecf061109844504a05387fb3d39e8f
anyone know what i am doing wrong and/or how i could fix it ?
thank you <3

```
package gui;

import tetris.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;


public class MultiPlayerWindow extends JPanel
{

private GameLoop gameLoop1 ;
private GameLoop gameLoop2 ;
private boolean gameLoopHasStarted1 ;
private boolean gameLoopHasStarted2 ;
private BoardHandler bh1 ;
private BoardHandler bh2 ;
private HighScoreList highScoreList;

private HumanInput inputController ;
private HumanInput inputController2 ;

private JPanel scorePanel;
private JPanel rightPanel;

    public MultiPlayerWindow( MainMenu mainMenu ){
    //create the variables
    Board board1 = new Board(10 , 20 ) ;
    Board board2 = new Board(10 , 20 ) ;
    final HumanInput inputController1 = new HumanInput() ;
    final HumanInput inputController2 = new HumanInput() ;
    this.bh1 = new BoardHandler(board1 , true) ;
    this.bh2 = new BoardHandler(board2 , true) ;
    this.highScoreList = new HighScoreList() ;

    //behaviour
    this.addKeyListener(inputController1);
    this.addKeyListener(inputController2);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocusInWindow() ;
    this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    //create panels
    scorePanel = new JPanel() ;
    scorePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    scorePanel.setSize(Config.LEFTPANEL_SIZE);
    rightPanel = new JPanel() ;
    rightPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    rightPanel.setSize(Config.RIGHTPANEL_SIZE);

    //create the ScoreBoard
    final ScoreBoard scoreBoard = new ScoreBoard() ;
    GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints() ;
    d.gridx = 0 ;
    d.gridy = 0 ;
    scorePanel.add(scoreBoard , d) ;
    d.insets = new Insets(30,10,10,0);
    //add a timer to update ScoreBoard
    new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //System.out.println("Trying to update score");
            scoreBoard.setScore(gameLoop1.getScore());
            scoreBoard.setScore(gameLoop2.getScore());
        }
    }).start();

    //create the Highscore Board
    HighScoreBoard highScoreBoard = new HighScoreBoard(highScoreList);
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 0;
    d.gridy = 1;
    d.insets = new Insets(30,10,10,0);
    scorePanel.add(highScoreBoard, d);

    //create the combobox to choose between tetris and pentris
    String[] optionStrings = {"Tetris", "Pentris"};
    final JComboBox optionList = new JComboBox(optionStrings);
    optionList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    optionList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(optionList.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
            {
                bh1.switchToTetris();
                bh2.switchToTetris();
            }
            else if(optionList.getSelectedIndex() == 1)
            {
                bh1.switchToPentris();
                bh2.switchToPentris();
            }
        }
    });

    optionList.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            optionList.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        }
    });

    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 0;
    d.gridy = 2;
    d.weightx = 0.5;
    d.insets = new Insets(30,10,10,0);
    scorePanel.add(optionList, d);

    //add the scorePanel
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 1;
    d.gridy = 0;
    this.add(scorePanel, d);

    final GamePanel gamePanel1 = new GamePanel(board1);
    final GamePanel gamePanel2 = new GamePanel(board2);
    gamePanel1.setSize(Config.GAMEPANEL_SIZE);
    gamePanel2.setSize(Config.GAMEPANEL_SIZE);
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 0;
    d.gridy = 0;
    this.add(gamePanel1, d);
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 2;
    d.gridy = 0;
    this.add(gamePanel2, d);


    //set the Thread
    gameLoop1 = new GameLoop(bh1, inputController1, gamePanel1, highScoreList);
    gameLoop2 = new GameLoop(bh2, inputController2, gamePanel2, highScoreList);
    gameLoop1.start();
    gameLoop2.start();
    gameLoopHasStarted1 = false;
    gameLoopHasStarted2 = false;

    //add the buttons
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setAlignmentX(30);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,10,10));
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 0;
    d.weightx = 0.2;
    d.gridy = 0;
    d.insets = new Insets(200,20,0,20);
    rightPanel.add(buttonPanel, d);

    //backbutton
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 0;
    d.gridy = 1;
    d.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
    d.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 20);
    rightPanel.add(new BackButton(mainMenu), d);

    //add the right panel
    d = new GridBagConstraints();
    d.gridx = 3;
    d.gridy = 0;
    this.add(rightPanel, d);

    final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    startButton.requestFocus(false);
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!gameLoopHasStarted1 && !gameLoopHasStarted2)
            {
                try{
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            gameLoopHasStarted1 = true;
                            gameLoopHasStarted2 = true;
                            gameLoop1.startNewGame();
                            gameLoop2.startNewGame();
                            optionList.setEnabled(false);
                            requestFocusInWindow();
                            startButton.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch(Exception expenction)
                {
                    expenction.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(startButton);

    //pause button
    final JButton pauseButton = new JButton("Pause  ");
    buttonPanel.add(pauseButton);
    pauseButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!gameLoop1.isPaused() && !gameLoop2.isPaused()) {
                gameLoop1.setPaused(true);
                gameLoop2.setPaused(true);
                pauseButton.setText("Unpause");
            }
            else if(gameLoop1.isPaused()&& gameLoop2.isPaused())
            {
                gameLoop1.setPaused(false);
                gameLoop2.setPaused(false);
                pauseButton.setText("Pause  ");
            }
        }
    });

    //reset button
    JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    buttonPanel.add(resetButton);
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            bh1.resetBoard();
            bh2.resetBoard();
            optionList.setEnabled(true);
            if(gameLoop1.isRunning() && gameLoop2.isRunning())
            {
                gameLoop1.apruptGameEnd();
                gameLoop2.apruptGameEnd();
            }
            gameLoopHasStarted1 = false;
            gameLoopHasStarted2 = false;
            gamePanel1.repaint();
            gamePanel2.repaint();
            startButton.setEnabled(true);
            gameLoop1.setPaused(false);
            gameLoop2.setPaused(false);
            pauseButton.setText("Pause");
            scoreBoard.setScore(0);

        }
    });

    //focuslistener for inputController
    this.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    });



}

public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return Config.SINGLE_PLAYER_SIZE;
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like your `GridBagConstraints` need touching up.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. 
i have been trying around with the `GridBagConstraints` (and the window dimensions) but i still dont get my boards to show up correctly.. even if there is enough space for sure..
https://gyazo.com/310677f290b0878abc961261ab6a3088

Comment: Try logging more to figure out what's the main suspect or do a debug session; simply posting your code and expecting someone to debug it for you *might be* expecting a bit too much :) After finding out the root cause of the problem, edit the OP with additional details and questions on solving that particular issue.

Comment: i have been doing this, but then the problem is that all my printstatements get executed (and printed in th command line)..
in the boardhandler, gameloop etc..
even in the multiplayerwindow..
so the game is basically running (quite perfectly) without showing that in the multiplayerwindow/gui..
like, if i start the game and just wait after a little the game ends and ask me to put in names for the highscorelist.

Comment: Redirect your logging to logs.txt file then... ?

Comment: i fixed it, 
https://gyazo.com/6e12c86f2554e0741fe0cb52b7a14697
the last line was messing something up.
`public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return Config.SINGLE_PLAYER_SIZE;
}`
thanks for your help/time tho
i'm new here, but if you tell me how i can up your rep let me know and i'll do so ;)

Comment: ok, will do
thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

fixed it.
`public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return Config.SINGLE_PLAYER_SIZE;
    }`
    this last part was what was messing it up, the rest of the code works fine but was previously then (for some tbh unknown reason) messed up by this. not 100% sure why...

Comment: Your answer could be displayed a little bit better :).